# Google maps api center on marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got the code below, which places 4 maps on a page, and adds a marker for each based on an address. But I need to map to center on the marker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var geocoder;
         var map0,map1,map2,map3;
         var markers = [];
          function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 14,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map0 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas1"), mapOptions);
            addPostCode('@address1',map0);
            map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), mapOptions);
            addPostCode('@address2',map1);
            map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas3"), mapOptions);
            addPostCode('@address3',map2);
            map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas4"), mapOptions);
            addPostCode('@address4',map3);
          }

          function addPostCode(address,map) {
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    center: results[0].geometry.location,
                    name: address
                });
                markers.push(marker);
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
                });
            }
```

Not totally sure where to make it center on the marker for that map.

Comment: This line makes no sense for the markers: `center: results[0].geometry.location,` - markers don't have a 'center', merely a position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I programmed working example which you can see from here: **[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUkCs/4/)**

Few things which I changed was removing `center: results[0].geometry.location` from marker (since markers are only added to locations and map controlled by using `map.setCenter();`) Also I changed names of classes a bit, so modify it as you like. cheers!